# Build multidimensional object from a URL

Tags: javascript, object, recursion

I like to create a object that looks like this for the following URL:

```
faq/jamie/hutber/faq.json
faq/jamie/hutber/faq_sales.json
sales/people/faq_refunds.json

{
    faq: {
       jamie: {
            hutber:[
               "faq.json",
               "faq_sales.json"
            ]
       }
    },
    sales: {
      people: [
         faq_refunds.json
      ]
    }
}
```

I feel confident to be able to build we'll need some kind of recursion... which I am lacking in.

```
const data = {}
const list = 'faq/jamie/hutber/faq.json'.split('/').reverse();
list.forEach((cur, index) => {
    if(cur.includes('.json')){
        data[cur];
    } else if(poo[cur]) {
        data[cur] = {}
   }else{
        data[cur] = {}
   }
});
```

Comment: Wheres the question?

Comment: Well what you've got there is not URL, it's 3 strings which could indeed each be seen as a path to a file. I also don't see any bug here nor any real attempt to build the desired outcome. Indeed recursion seems to be a good idea, so let's start to code :-)

Comment: @Liam its the title of the question. I would like an object.

Comment: So you just want someone to do this for you?

Comment: that is 100% correct. I do indeed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this in a loop. Note that you won't support folders that contain both folders *and* files in your current format.

Here's an example that loops over all paths and adds object to the tree. It's a bit ugly, but it should help you write your own function.

```js
const paths = [
  "faq/jamie/hutber/faq.json",
  "faq/jamie/hutber/faq_sales.json",
  "sales/people/faq_refunds.json"
];


const makeTree = (paths, tree = {}) =>
  paths.reduce(
    (tree, path) => {
      const parts = path.split("/");
      const folders = parts.slice(0, -2);
      const container = parts[parts.length - 2];
      const file = parts[parts.length - 1];
      let loc = tree;
      
      folders.forEach(f => {
        loc[f] = loc[f] || {};
        loc = loc[f];
      });
      
      loc[container] = loc[container] || [];
      loc[container].push(file);
      return tree;
    },
    tree
  );
  
console.log(makeTree(paths));
```

Comment: Interesting, I went down reduce path, but I never for whatever reason thought about putting a `forEach` inside the reduce lol

Answer (score 1):

```js
var a = ["faq/jamie/hutber/faq.json",
   "faq/jamie/hutber/faq_sales.json", 
   "sales/people/faq_refunds.json"]; //your URLs

var jsonObj = {}; //this json object will store your result
   
function urlToJson(array, index, jsonObj){ //function that implements your logic

 if(index == array.length - 2){
  jsonObj[ array[index] ] = jsonObj[ array[index] ] || [];
  jsonObj[ array[index] ].push(array[index + 1]);
  return;
 }
  jsonObj[ array[index] ] = jsonObj[ array[index] ] || {};
  urlToJson(array, index + 1, jsonObj[ array[index] ]);     
}

for(var key in a){
 var array = a[key].split("/");
 urlToJson(array, 0, jsonObj);
}
console.log(jsonObj);
```